# Manipulating huge data in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written some VBA code to put custom checks on the data entered in data sheet. Currently i am using Workbook_BeforeSave event to get all the validation data from validation sheet and perform validation on data entered in data sheet . Based on the validation error i add comment to the data sheet cells. The problem is that it works fine for hundred records in data sheet but when it comes to thousands of records it takes several minutes. And the ask is to do it for data that might be close to 50K records or more.
Do excel VBA script provide support for  multithreading?
Or is there any other way to do the same?

I have searched for multithreading in VBA but the answer is no, in some posts it shows possible but they can't work on active worksheet simultaneously.

Please suggest.

*Data might be copied from other sheet also in the data sheet.

I check for validations before save button click:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim i As Integer
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
     ' Begin the loop.
     For i = 1 To WS_Count

        ' Insert your code here.
        ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
        ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
        If Not ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name = "Validation Data" Then
            CheckForCellValidation ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
        End If
     Next i
 End Sub
```

Below is my validation check method for range in sheet it finds target range and based on column id it checks for validation:

```
Function CheckForCellValidation(ByVal sheetName As String)
Dim rng As Range
Dim sheetRng As Range
Dim varRng As Range
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim colName As String
Dim valOption As Long
Dim param
Dim errMsges
Dim Larr
Dim errMsg As String

Set rng = {Get all entries in validation sheet}

For Each cell In rng.Cells
    Set varRng = cell.Offset(1, 0)
    param = Split(varRng.Offset(1, 0).Value2, ":;") 'parameter in validation sheet, see attached image(multiple validations can be present for one column)
errMsges = Split(varRng.Offset(2, 0).Value2, ":;") 'error message, see attached image
Larr = Split(varRng.Value2, ":;")

Set sheetRange = Sheets(sheetName).Cells.Find(what:=cell.Value2, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not sheetRange Is Nothing Then
    colName = Replace(sheetRange(1).Address(0, 0), sheetRange(1).row, "")
    strVal = Sheets(sheetName).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'Data entry starts from 7th row in data sheet
    Set sheetRange = Sheets(sheetName).Range(colName & CStr(7) & ":" & colName & strVal)
    sheetRange.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    sheetRange.Cells.ClearComments

    For i = 0 To UBound(Larr)
        valOption = Larr(i)

        If UBound(errMsges) >= i Then
          errMsg = errMsges(i)
        Else
          errMsg = ""
        End If

    Select Case valOption
    Case Is = 1
        For Each cel In sheetRange.Cells
        ValidateMandatoryField cel, errMsg
        Next cel       

    Case Is = 6
    For Each cel In sheetRange.Cells
        ValidateRegEx cel, param(i), errMsg
    Next cel

    Case Is = 8
    For Each cel In sheetRange.Cells
    ValidateMinTextLength cel, param(i), errMsg
    Next cel

    Case Is = 9
    For Each cel In sheetRange.Cells
        ValidateNumericalLength cel, param(i), errMsg
    Next cel
    End Select
  Next i
  End If
Next cell
End Function
```

Sample data in validation sheet attached:
[image]

Comment: Excel vba is single threaded. If you are after code optimization then you may have an eligible question for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. Be sure to read the instructions on posting there though. You can use [DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/doevents-function) to yield control to the operating system so to speak.

Comment: I have like 9 validation checks for different columns(column count might vary on sheet to sheet 50-150), each validation contains not more that 10 lines of code accessing validation check and cell data.

Comment: Sounds like a code review question though you need to post with a title that says what the code does, post the entire code, explain what is does etc. Read the how to ask for code review in link I gave above. Otherwise, use a language/app that does support multi-threading.

Comment: The question is too broad - either you post some code to a code review site. Or you find a method for multithreading, and if you're stuck: come back to stackoverflow with a reproducable question. "Please suggest" is like asking: please google for me.

Comment: I have added the code for an example to show how i am doing it. Is there anything i can do to improve my code or use something else to improve the performance as sheet gets stuck for several minutes when thousands of records are verified from code.

Answer (score 0):

Excel and VBA are definitely NOT multi-threading technologies.

You could use Windows Task Scheduler to open your Workbook, fire and Open_Workbook event, and run your script sometime after you leave the office (i.e., run the take each evening at midnight, save all changes, and the results will be waiting for you when you get into the office in the morning).

https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html